# in react native want to get Home Page data according with respect to logged in email

Tags: express, react-native

In my project i logged in with email password, after that want to get Home Page data according with respect to logged in email, The API will return the response data for that specific user, in **useState()** i have passed static email, which i need to change dynamic 
**Home Page code :**

````
```import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { Button} from 'react-native-paper';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';

const ProductScreen = (props) => {
 const [email]= useState('test@xyz.com')    
  const sendCred = async (props)=>{
    fetch("http://test.com:70/api/productForClient",{
      method:"POST",
      headers: {        
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
      },
     body:JSON.stringify({
       "email":email,
      })
    })
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then((data)=>{
      console.log("*****************************", data)
    })
 }

 return (
   <> 
   <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position">
     <StatusBar backgroundColor="blue" barStyle="light-content" />
      <Text 
      style={{fontSize:35,marginLeft:18,marginTop:10,color:"#3b3b3b"}}>welcome to</Text>

      <Button 
        mode="contained"
        style={{marginLeft:18,marginRight:18,marginTop:18}}
       onPress={() => sendCred(props)}>
        Get Data
      </Button>      
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text
      style={{
        fontSize:18,marginLeft:18,marginTop:20
      }}
      onPress={()=>props.navigation.replace("signup")}
      >dont have a account ?</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
   </>
  );
};
export default ProductScreen;```
````

Comment: i didn't get the questions properly, u want to get Home Page data according with respect to logged in email ?

Comment: yes sir, i have passed static email const [email]= useState('test@xyz.com') , i want to use logged in email

Comment: add HomePage code

Comment: Above mentioned code is for homePage

Comment: what version of react-navigation u are using

Comment: react-navigation version:
"@react-navigation/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.25",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.0-alpha.16",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.0-alpha.38",

Answer (score 0):

On Your Login Screen,
pass the email in the navigation statement.

Like:

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate('Home',{email: "You Email Id using"});
```

And on your Home screen, use it like:

```
fetch("http://test.com:70/api/productForClient",{
  method:"POST",
  headers: {        
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
  },
 body:JSON.stringify({
   "email":props.navigation.state.params.email,
  })
})
```

There is one more alternative, set the email in the AsyncStorage on login, and access it from AsyncStorage whenever you want to use it.

One more alternative is use redux, and save email in your redux store, and access it wherever you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

when user loggs in with email and password if login is successful pass the email from Login Page to Home Page and then in Home page use routes prop to get the email then do your stuff,,

here is a simple example

Login Page

```
const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('email');

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const login = () => {
    // Login to server on Success
    // call navigation.navigate
    navigation.navigate('Home', { email })
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Login" onPress={login}/>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Home Page

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {useRoute} from '@react-navigation/native'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const Home = () => {

  const route = useRoute();

  useEffect(() => {
    const email = route.params.email;
    // get Data from  the server
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text>Home</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do small changes.

Pass `email` from the login screen to the home screen like below example;

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate('Home',{email: "You Email Id using"});
```

And no need to show any default email. Just do something like this

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash'; // use can you any other if you like instead of lodash
import { Button} from 'react-native-paper';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';

const ProductScreen = (props) => {
// Retrive email from props. `_.get` method only check if data not available the // set `undefined`. 
 const [email]= useState(_.get(props.navigation, 'state.params.email'));    
  const sendCred = async (props)=>{
    fetch("http://test.com:70/api/productForClient",{
      method:"POST",
      headers: {        
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
      },
     body:JSON.stringify({
       "email":email,
      })
    })
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then((data)=>{
      console.log("*****************************", data)
    })
 }

 return (
   <> 
   <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position">
     <StatusBar backgroundColor="blue" barStyle="light-content" />
      <Text 
      style={{fontSize:35,marginLeft:18,marginTop:10,color:"#3b3b3b"}}>welcome to</Text>

      <Button 
        mode="contained"
        style={{marginLeft:18,marginRight:18,marginTop:18}}
       onPress={() => sendCred(props)}>
        Get Data
      </Button>      
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text
      style={{
        fontSize:18,marginLeft:18,marginTop:20
      }}
      onPress={()=>props.navigation.replace("signup")}
      >dont have a account ?</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
   </>
  );
};
export default ProductScreen
```